# Web Scraping with rvest package don't work

Tags: r, web, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get a table with rvest but it doesn't recognize the numbers and creates two extra columns with NAs

A few months ago it worked, but apparently they made changes to the website and now it doesn't work.I do not know what the problem may be.

```
  url <- paste0("https://climatologia.meteochile.gob.cl/application/mensual/temperaturaMediaMensual/170007/2021/08")
tmp <- read_html(url)
tmp <- html_nodes(tmp,"table")
sapply(tmp, function(x) dim(html_table(x, fill = TRUE))) ## ver tabla con datos
tabla <- html_table(tmp[1],fill = T,header=NA, dec = ".")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that when looking at the web page there are numbers in the table, but when capturing it with web scrapping the values do not appear

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with recognising numbers. There are two empty columns in the html, hence the NAs, and most of the table is blank.

As there are repeat headers, I use janitor to clean the headers, then dplyr to remove the end columns which are automatically labelled x and x_2. You could also slice end columns off instead.

I would probably consider removing/putting into separate table the `Resumen Mensual` part of the current table.

```
library(rvest)
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

url <- paste0("https://climatologia.meteochile.gob.cl/application/mensual/temperaturaMediaMensual/170007/2021/08")

t <- read_html(url) |> 
  html_element('#excel > table') |>
  html_table() |>  
  clean_names() |> 
  select(!starts_with('x'))

t
```

---

The new base pipe |> requires  [R 4.1.0](https://michaelbarrowman.co.uk/post/the-new-base-pipe/). You can replace with %>% pipe from magrittr

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why is the table blank? If when entering the link you have data in the columns.

That I have not been able to know why it happens.